# C# Enumeration Issue

Tags: c#, enums, preprocessor

I'm currently designing a Game Engine in C#. The engine has multiple driver types (OpenGL, DirectX). However each driver type requires different key codes when the user presses a button. But for some reason, using preprocessors isn't working... mind you I'm very new to using them.

I really think (like in most cases) the best way to get someone to understand what i'm trying to do is to show some code.

Here is my KeyCode enumeration (or part of it):

```
public enum KeyCode
{
#if DRIVER_TYPE_OPENGL
        A = 83,
        B = 84
#elif DRIVER_TYPE_DRIECTX
        A = 65,
        B = 66
#endif
}
```

At the top of my OpenGL Window class, I have done this:

```
#define DRIVER_TYPE_OPENGL
```

and at the top of my DirectX Window class, I have done this:

```
#define DRIVER_TYPE_DRIECTX
```

From what I understand, I should now be able to do something like this:

```
        IDisplay display = new OpenGLDisplay(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE);

        while (true)
        {
            // Do stuff with display

            // Process input like so:
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You're using OpenGL driver, good on you!")
            }

            // Swap buffers and stuff
        }

        display.Close();
```

But instead, I get an error saying: "KeyCode does not contain a definition for 'A'"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not using switch-case?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh Because I can't use switch-case inside an enumeration and I'd rather not have both "OpenGLKeyCode" & "DirectXKeyCode" enumerations.

Comment: @aaron that will only make the A value 65, and not allow me to switch between OpenGL & DirectX key code values.

Comment: @tdkr80 Where did you define your enum ?

Comment: @Blacktempel it's defined outside of any classes and completely by it's self.

Comment: This might sound dumb but you don't have a different local variable named 'KeyCode' do you? Did you try testing the enum without the #if #elif #endif statement?

Comment: @mattshu Blacktempel has just posted an answer that has helped me understand the problem. Hopefully this will clear things up for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your enum or use project-wide defines.

The define will only work in the file you `#define` it.
This is C#, not C++ with headers.

Comment: I figured that might be the case. How do I use project-wide defines?

Comment: @tdkr80 Right click on your project, Properties -> Build -> Conditional compilation symbols.

Comment: @tdkr80 See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995869/how-to-set-project-wide-define-in-c-sharp

Comment: But I still won't be able to undefine or define them outside of the KeyCodes scope, will I?

Comment: @tdkr80 You can `#undef` or `#define` on the top of your file. But only for the whole and single file.